# How can I collect pairs of numbers from multiples inputs, then print them all at once at the end?

Tags: python, input

I have several `inputs` that will general outputs that are pairs of numbers. And I want to collect these pairs and print them out at the end.

e.g.

`first input()` produces ->

```
2 3
4 6
5 9
29 99 
33 12
```

`second input()` produces ->

```
4 5 
9 9 
44 5
```

`third input()` produces ->

```
5 5 
9 9
10 10
```

And instead of printing the output of the three individual inputs, I want to store them somewhere, then print once the inputs have finished running.

Is there anyway to use `yield/generator`? Because I am conscious that we have multiple inputs and this will not work. Will it work if I run the generator for each input?

Otherwise, would I need to store the pair of integers in an array perhaps?

**Input Format**

The first line of input contains a `single integer T`
, denoting the number of test cases. The description of T
test cases follows.

Each testcase consists of a single line of input, containing `two integers N,M` ; the number of vertices and edges of the graph you must construct.

Here is my code, although I think it is only the last batch that is relevant:

```
from collections import defaultdict

T = int(input())

for _ in range(T):
    N, M = map(int, input().split())
    arrayOfNodes = [i for i in range(1, N + 1)]
    numberOfBridges = N - 1
    edgesLeft = M - (N - 1)

    # building number of edges left- to determine max # of briges we can achieve
    bridgeBurn = defaultdict(int)
    bridgeBurn[1] = -2
    count = -2
    for edge in range(2, N):
        count -= 1
        m = (edge * (edge + 1)) // 2
        bridgeBurn[m] = count

    # determine how many bridges to burn
    bridgesToBurn = 0
    for topInterval in bridgeBurn:

        if topInterval== edgesLeft:
            bridgesToBurn = bridgeBurn[topInterval]
            break

        elif topInterval > edgesLeft:
            bridgesToBurn = bridgeBurn[topInterval]+1
            break

    finalNumberOfBridges = numberOfBridges + bridgesToBurn

    for edge in range(1, len(arrayOfNodes)):
        print(f"{arrayOfNodes[0]} {arrayOfNodes[edge]}")

    if M == N-1:
        continue

    elif M > N - 1:
        while edgesLeft>0:
            for edge in range(2, N+1 - finalNumberOfBridges):
                for edge2 in range(edge + 1, N+1 - finalNumberOfBridges):
                    print(f"{edge} {edge2}")
                    edgesLeft -= 1
```

Comment: append outputs to a list then print them out by iterating over the list at the end

Comment: Thanks Matiiss, but how can I append two digits; initially I was using a f-string to print the two numbers, as I am doing this on a coding website and they are very particular about the format of the output!

Comment: It would be helpful if you added the `input()` functions' code, so we could get the return format without any edits.

Comment: Okay, let me add it- the code is quite long but I'll explain it the best I can

Comment: You may realise that at the end I didn't use `arrayOfNodes`, because I realised I didn't really need it!

Answer (score 0):

In your functions, use `return [x, y]` (where x and y are lists of what you were printing -> edge and edge2 or arrayOfNodes and arrayOfNodes2) just to make it easier to store.

So the simplified problem would be something like:

```
def input1():
    return [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
...
```

I'm just going to put out the code for storing the returned variables here:

It could probably be made less of an eyesore but it works perfectly

```
def imp1():
    return [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]


def imp2():
    return [["a", 'b', 'c'], ['z', 'y', 'x']]


def imp3():
    return [[0, 1, 2, 3], [3, 2, 1, 0]]


val = []

for i in [imp1, imp2, imp3]:
    [x, y] = i()

    val += [[x, y]]

print(val)
for i in val:
    for j, k in i, val[val.index(i) + 1]:
        for l in range(len(k)):
            print(j[l], k[l])
```